# sed - remove dates from each line of file

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to get rid of the dates  - all of them from 2015 -present 2017.
I want to rename each `foo_data_$date` to just `foo_data_*`. I just need the files name. Not all the individual dates. 
I do not understand the regex for sed - I can do it in perl with perl -nle 'print /(foo_data_)\d+txt) but can't figure out how to do it with sed.
I want to do it in sed because I have been using sed -i flag and changing the file in place.

```
cat /tmp/foo | head | sed -e 's/foo_data_20*txt/foo_data_\*/g'
foo_data_20150901.txt
foo_data_20150902.txt
foo_data_20150906.txt
foo_data_20150907.txt
foo_data_20150908.txt
foo_data_20150909.txt
foo_data_20150912.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just run sed like this.

```
sed -e 's/foo_data_[0-9]*/foo_data_/g'
```

Now, for the thing to capture dates only between 2015 and 2017, this will make it.

```
sed -e 's/foo_data_201\(5\|6\|7\)[0-9]*/foo_data_/g'
```

Then you will remove the dates from the file names in your file.

Comment: I think OP actually wants `*` in the result. Just add `*` before the last slash. There's no need to quote `*` on the right side of a substitution. Also, there's no need for `g` at the end unless there's more than one substitution to make on a line.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mention foo_data:

```
sed -i 's/201[567][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]//'
```

Your command was wrong: `/foo_data_20*txt/` will match a '0' 0 or more times (something like `foo_data_2000000000000txt`).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to rename the files, most Linux distros (assuming you're *on* Linux) have a `rename` utility that handles Perl regular expressions just fine:

```
pax> touch pax_100.txt ; touch pax_200.txt
pax> rename -n 's/_(\d)/_diablo_$1/' pax*
rename(pax_100.txt, pax_diablo_100.txt)
rename(pax_200.txt, pax_diablo_200.txt)
```

The `-n` options shows what will happen rather than doing the rename. Once you're satisfied, simply remove it.

Oh, and one final note. If you remove the dates from all those file names, they'll all have the *same* file name. Unless your file names are just test data, that's probably going to need some further thought on your part.